# redirect certain domain to different folders failing in nginx

Tags: http, nginx, server

I have three subdomains like `m.xyz.com`, `test.xyz.com`, `prod.xyz.com`, `main.xyz.com`. If I redirect my sub domain then it automatically locates the default folder path of the web site. I want to redirect all sub domains to different folder location. I'm using nginx server in centos, even after creating four separate `.conf` file it is redirecting to the default location.

`.conf` file code is as follows:

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  m.xyz.com www.m.xyz.com;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/folder1/location1/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ @extensionless-php;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/xyz/xyz-php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_pass 192.168.1.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    # rewrites
    location @extensionless-php {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }
    charset utf-8;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add some configuration files.

Comment: I want add _n.xyz.com_ with _folder2/location2_ . Even after creating anothe .conf file it is redirecting to the _folder1/location1_ . What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by *redirect my sub domain*, because `redirect` has a specific meaning. If you need three subdomains each with a unique root, then you need three `server` containers, similar to the one you posted, except three of them. Just change `server_name` and `root` for each one.